# Is there any shortcut for this logical operator?

Tags: c#, php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was just wondering if there is a shortcut to do something like this example :

```
if ( isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] == 'George' || $_POST['name'] == 'Mike' );
```

[EDIT] : Sorry if the question seemed ambiguous at first but what I meant to ask is "since I am doing all those checks on the same variable is there a better way not to write it three times?"

is there any easier way that is rare and ..

1. cleaner than nesting.
2. shorter than the syntax above?
3. in any of (Ruby, C#, or PHP) since I mainly use those 3 languages.

This is just a general knowledge question, I was just getting bored of writing nested ifs or long logical operations like the one above.

Comment: When would !empty($_POST['name']) ever be false if $_POST['name'] == 'something' is true? Not sure what you're asking for here.

Comment: i am sorry i was just writing an example of doing many operations on the same variable i'll edit it to something more practical

Comment: @aquinas: if post was `0`... There's a few things that count as `empty()` in PHP's twisted sad world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a function for getting post data:

```
function getPOST($name) {
  return isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : null;
}
```

The function will never show the notice about accessing a not existing array field and the result can be easily compared to the list of values in your example:

```
if (in_array(getPOST('name'), array('George', 'Mike')) {

}
```

Comment: Yeah i thought it wasn't "something" built in in any of these languages core libs, i ask only when i don't know how to form the google question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question right, but looks like you want to compare a particular variable to a set of values. You can do the following:

1. Put all the values in an array.
2. Check the variable if it is set.
3. Use `in_array` function to find if the value of the variable exists in the array of values.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby

```
if $_POST['name'] && ['George', 'Mike'].include?($_POST['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset` to make sure the value is not `NULL` and then `strlen` to make sure you actually have something in there.

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) > 0)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function post_data($key){
    if(isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key]!='') return $_POST[$key];
    return null;
}

$possible_names  = array('George', 'Mike');

if(in_array(post_data('name'), $possible_names)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is extremely general. How can you not use the same variable name many times? Well, what does your code look like and I'll tell you :) In *general* that's not really a possible question to answer. In your example case, you could do something like this (in C#):

```
string x = "foo";
if ( new string[]{"bar","baz","foo","foobar"}.Contains(x)) ....
```

Or:

```
public static class Extensions {
        public static bool In<T>(this T needle, params T[] haystack){
            return haystack.Contains(needle);
        }
    }


string x = "foo";
if (x.In("bar", "baz", "foo", "foobar")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony 1.4 framework utilizes [`sfParameterHolder`](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfParameterHolder) to deal with the problem of trying to determine whether an element is present in an array.

You could clean things up a bit by copying/duplicating the functionality of `sfParameterHolder` in your project.

You can also use a `switch` statement if you prefer that syntax to clean up all the values in your conditionals.

The end result might look something like this:

```
$post = new sfParameterHolder($_POST);

switch( $post->get('name') )
{
  case 'george':
  case 'mike':
    // Do something.
    break;
}
```